# Multilevel modeling in R: Is it possible to have an “coherence/concordance variable” as outcome?

Tags: r, regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I am working on a paper about sexual coherence in women. Sexual coherence is defined as the relationship between subjective (SA) and genital sexual (GA) arousal. There is research that shows that this coherence can be higher or lower, depending on other factors, like age or arousability...

Both measures (SA and GA) have been measured continuously over a period of 5 minutes. I divided these 5-minutes into 15-second intervalls and calculated the mean for both arousal measures for each section.

Additionally, I have 2 questionnaire scores (P1, P2) that might influence SA, GA or (most importantly) the relationship between SA and GA

I use the package nlme in R and my data is transformed into long format.

My first question: Is it, in your opinion, possible to assess sexual coherence between GA and SA with a regression analysis, in which SA is the outcome and GA is the predictor?

My second question: If I want to investigate the impact of P1 and P2 on sexual concordance (the association between GA and SA), is it feasible to add the questionnaires to the above mentioned regression?
The model would look something like this: Coherence.model <-nlme ( SA ~ GA + P1 + P2 + (GAP1) + (GAP2) + (P1*P2)) My idea is that you can assess the direct influence of GA, P1 and P2 on SA and (if the interaction terms (GA*P1) is significant) you can say that, e.g., P1 is a moderator of the relationship between GA and SA.

What do you think? Or do you have another idea, who to work with an "coherence measure" as outcome variable?

Best, Julia

Please excuse that I did not get into detail regarding syntax or programming. But I hope that this is not necessary at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are spot on if you want to model the effect of GA on SA. The interaction terms, as you say, will describe the modulating effects of P1 and P2 on the effect of GA on SA.

You might also consider not taking the mean of the 15 second intervals but using the data from all the intervals, with time (meaning the 20 different time points) as a non-linear effect (if it is appropriate) and subject id as a random effect. You might get more interesting and detailed results that way.